# Locking text to front in fabric.js (not bringing to front each time)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way without using:

```
canvas.sendBackwards(myObject)
canvas.sendToBack(myObject)
```

Basically I want to be able to upload multiple images, while having them be able to go forward and back of each, but never reaching the highest layer (should always be text, even if there are more than 2 text layers)

Would I be best to group all text layers, and run bringToFront, any time an image is uploaded/item is moved forward/backwards? Or is there a better way to lock their z-index position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric.JS doesn't really have true z-index functionality as you see with css. Instead, objects on the canvas work like an array where the index of each object determines where it sits in the stacking order. Using 'canvas.insertAt()' to add an object will let you specify a specific index to insert the object in the array, and the length of the array is always determined by how many objects there are in your canvas.

Inserting an object at an index of 0 will therefore shift the other objects within the array so that the new object is rendered at the bottom of the stacking order.

Comment: I thought that was the case, is it possible to lock array positions? For example, once text is added to index 0, don’t allow anything else move to 0?

Comment: The best way would be to use `canvas.add()` for the images and `canvas.insertAt()` for the text to make sure images are never placed atop text in the stacking order.